# Java GUI locking up - boolean value not working as expected?

Tags: java, swing, networking

I'm making a Java based server application. For some reason my GUI is locking up when I retrieve a file list from the server. I send the server a message "listFiles", then the server responds with "LIST" - which is when the code below is executed.

```
private Boolean wait = true;

// Handle server output.
private class ServerOutput implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        String serverMsg;
        while ((serverMsg = reader.nextLine()) != null) {
            try {
                if (serverMsg.equals("LIST")) {

                    wait = true;

                    fileList = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).readObject();


                    fileArray = (File[]) fileList;

                    for(File file : fileArray){
                        System.out.println(file.getName());
                    }

                    wait = false;

                    }

    public Boolean getState(){
        return wait;
    }

    public File[] getFileList(){
        return fileArray;
    }
...
```

The GUI should be stuck in a while loop until "wait = true". Sometimes it works, and other times it just gets stuck in the loop, even though the client has definitely received the fileList because it successfully prints it out.

Here's the code for the action listener attached to the connect button:

```
try {
        fc = new FileClient(serverAddress, serverPort);


        fc.send("listFiles","null");

        while (fc.getState()) {

        }

        File[] fileList = fc.getFileList();
 ...
```

Comment: (i) you don't need a `Boolean`, a `boolean` would do. (ii) if several threads are involved, you probably need to make wait volatile: `private volatile boolean wait = true;`

Comment: There is no guarantee that `wait` will be set to `true` immediately after the `fc.send(...)` call, so the `while` loop might not be entered. There are much, much better ways to communicate between threads than this.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is flagrantly breaking Swing threading rules with the `while (...)` loop being called on the Swing event thread. Don't do that. Instead use a SwingWorker. You can easily be notified of when a SwingWorker is done by adding a PropertyChangeWorker to it, and once it has completed, then extract the result returned by it by calling `get()` on the worker. The [SwingWorker Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) can show you the details.

Your code could look something like:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // create the SwingWorker
    MyFileWorker myFileWorker = new MyFileWorker();

    // attach a PropertyChangeListener to it
    myFileWorker.addPropertyChangeListener(new MyFileWorkerListener());

    // and run the worker
    myFileWorker.execute();
}
```

and elsewhere:

```
private class MyFileWorker extends SwingWorker<File[], Void> {
    // must initialize the readers, sockets....
    // probably with data passed into this worker's construtor
    private BufferedReader reader = null; // fix this
    private Socket socket = null;  // fix this

    @Override
    protected File[] doInBackground() throws Exception {
        String serverMsg;
        while ((serverMsg = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (serverMsg.equals("LIST")) {
                File[] fileArray = (File[]) new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()).readObject();
                return fileArray;
            }
        }

        // if LIST never found
        return null;
    }

}

private class MyFileWorkerListener implements PropertyChangeListener {
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getNewValue() != SwingWorker.StateValue.DONE) {
            return;
        }

        MyFileWorker myFileWorker = (MyFileWorker) evt.getSource();
        try {

            // get File array
            files = myFileWorker.get();

            // here notify GUI that files have been found

        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```